# Can I get a timeline of changes for a specific dropbox folder

Tags: dropbox

I have a large dropbox repository, with a lot of daily changes. And a directory several levels down in that repository, that hasn't changed for several months.

I know how to get a 'timeline of changes' through the web interface for the top folder, but how can I get a 'timeline of changes' for just that directory?